# Google charts legend pile up

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Google charts does automatic label positioning. However under chrome everything goes ok, but under firefox and IE this is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftXgF.png

As anyone gone through this or have any idea why this happens? It's a very random behaviour sometimes it displays properlly other times it doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The html element where the graphic is going to be displayed must be visible at drawing time.

That's the solution. Otherwise there is a bug that in browsers other than chrome it cluters up the legends.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a reference to how/where you found/discovered this little tidbit? This wound up being the solution to my problem, and you're the first person to mention it... :p

Comment: The reference is myself :p I found it through the nasty process called cross browser debugging :)

Comment: Happens in Chrome 30.0.1599.101 for me.